# why isn't my output value different from the expected value when I try to submitted the problem

Tags: python-3.x

This is the two sum problem in [leetcode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/):

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        for i in nums:
            for j in nums:
                value = i + j
                if value == target and i != j:
                    return [nums.index(i),nums.index(j)]
```

when I ran the code, my output is `[0,1]`, which is the same as the expected output, but when I submit the the question, the output is null. I just started learning coding, so please be as specific as possible. Thanks

Comment: 1) This problem is much easier to solve with a `dict`. 2) What happens in your code if there are no two numbers that add up to the desired value? 3) What if my list is `[2, 2]` with a desired value of `4` (your code breaks). 4) With your current solution I would work with indices not actually values (your solution will time out on later test cases because it is O(n^2).

Comment: What will help you make it much more efficient will be [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: @Tomerikoo Slightly more efficient than the current solution but still inefficient. Can be done with `O(n)` time.

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues which I will help you fix but your solution probably still won't pass because of how slow it is.

Instead of going over every element using the second loop just go over the elements after the index of the first loop. (This also means you don't need to check if the indices are the same).

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)): # Only go i to end
                value = nums[i] + nums[j]
                if value == target:
                    return [i, j]
        return None # Its better to explicitly say what your are returning.
```

Note that the solution above is still extremely inefficient. You can do this faster using a `dict` since dictionaries have a `O(1)` look up time (in most cases), making the following solution `O(n)`.

```
class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        passed = dict()
        for index, num in enumerate(nums):
            if target - num in passed:
                return [passed[target - num], index]
            else:
                passed[num] = index
```

Comment: second loop should start from `i+1` no?